# Any api in iOS6 to get static map image of a gps location

Tags: ios, image, ios6, maps

I want a static map image from a location. I have the latitude and longitude of that location. Is there any api in iOS 6 to get the apple map static image of a gps location.

Answer (score 5):

MKMapView has two properties to achieve this functionality: `scrollEnabled` and `zoomEnabled`. Set both to `NO` and you'll have a non-scrolling and non-zooming (thus static) map image.

Comment: This is also how I would achieve this.

Comment: Don't forget about `pitchEnabled` and `rotateEnabled`

Answer (score 3):

I believe [Google Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) is what you're looking for. Send it the parameters of location and it will return the image you want.

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer: I've suggested an alternative, what's wrong with that? Google Static Maps gives a lot of options and much better maps.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 7+ Apple MapKit allows displaying static images of a map using [`MKMapSnapshotter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapsnapshotter) class. It is detailed in [Creating a Snapshot of a Map](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW13) section of MapKit documentation:

```
// Takes a snapshot and calls back with the generated UIImage
static func takeSnapshot(mapView: MKMapView, withCallback: (UIImage?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let options = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
    options.region = mapView.region
    options.size = mapView.frame.size
    options.scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    let snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
    snapshotter.startWithCompletionHandler() { snapshot, error in
        guard snapshot != nil else {
            withCallback(nil, error)
            return
        }

        withCallback(snapshot!.image, nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use MKMapView to display map ,you will have to use MapKit.framework for that

this link will help you...

https://github.com/kviksilver/MKMapview-annotation-grouping

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need a static image of the map in a location.